# Symfony2 MethodNotAllowedHttpException on live server

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I am getting below error on live server:

> request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException:
>   "No route found for "GET user/create: Method Not Allowed (Allow:
>   POST)" at /home/public_html/project/app/cache/prod/classes.php line
>   3685

but I am not getting this error on a local machine with the same code.

Solutions points to clearing the cache, but I am not able to get how we can clear cache on a live server.

I also deleted cache folder from live server, but the issue still persists.

**UPDATE:**
The issue is surprisingly solved after updating base.html.twig file. i think cache regenerates again with some dependencies after that. but still i did not get how it is resolved as deleting cache folder does not resolved it but changes in base.html.twig file does the job.

Comment: Will you a code snippet of your routing for the `user/create` route?

Comment: have you changed your environment to production ? `prod`.
Also if you can't to figure it out, i have some solution for you. You can listen for exception and return error response. Some example:
http://jameshalsall.co.uk/posts/displaying-exception-messages-in-symfony-production-environments. If this suit your needs i will post it as an answer

Comment: 1. Did you clear opcache / apc? 2. Do you use the same env on local and server? 3. Do you use standard or apache router?4. Which scheme do you use to define routes?

Comment: Have you tried checking the routes by using the command `php app/console router:debug`? It seems you are calling the `user/create` by `GET` method when the only method allowed for that route is `POST`.

Comment: there is a config file for dev environment routes, `routing_dev.yml`. check if you defined the route `user/create` for `GET` there

Comment: Compare the results of the followings: `app/console debug:router --env=dev` and `app/console debug:router --env=prod` and paste the results here if you still couldn't figure it out

Comment: regarding all GET/POST method comments, the route is never changed  and it is working fine previously. second thing i take down code on local and in prod mode in local issue is not reproducible .

Answer (score 4):

Try to run `php app/console router:debug  | grep user/create` to check if this route loaded at all. Maybe you load this route only for specific env.

Comment: @jit - Can you update your question with snippet where you define your route?

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have to call you route with "POST method.
Try to remove @Method("POST") in you controller or Add GET with @Route("GET","POST"). [Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-http-method-requirements)

Or try this following command :

```
php app/console cache:clear -e prod
```

Otherwise, delete app/cache folder.

Comment: already tried delete app/cache folder on production. but still error exists

Comment: @jit if clearing cache still does not work, look into the permission of the user (open the dbase table user or the same and look at the permission for that user and change it to admin if necessary)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
rm -rf app/logs/*

chmod 777 app/cache/
chmod 777 app/logs/
```

If problem solved, read more in "Setting up Permissions" section: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

Comment: already tried delete app/cache folder on production. but still error exists. cache on production creating after it. does we need 777 ? currently it is 755

Comment: Try 777, I think you have problem with permission for apache

Comment: If you set permissions 755 from your account so Apache does not have permission to write to cache and logs folders, because Apache in other group.